# Get count for date column(string) in 30 mins interval using sql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mongodb

I have a database with the following columns

```
Data | timeAdded | status
a    | 2022-01-05T00:00:00.0000 | sent
a    | 2022-01-05T00:10:00.0000 | received
a    | 2022-01-05T00:17:00.0000 | sent
a    | 2022-01-05T11:21:00.0000 | sent
a    | 2022-01-05T11:29:00.0000 | received
b    | 2022-01-05T15:09:00.0000 | sent
a    | 2022-01-05T17:29:02.0000 | rejected
b    | 2022-01-05T18:09:30.0000 | sent
```

The timeAdded column is a type of string. I need a sql query to find count for how many times data 'a' occured in each 30 mins, throughout a day.
so the result would be

```
Data | Time                     | count
a    |2022-01-05T00:00:00.0000  | 3
a    |2022-01-05T00:30:00.0000  | 0
a    |2022-01-05T01:00:00.0000  | 0
            .
            .
            .
a    |2022-01-05T11:00:00.0000  | 2
```

and so on for 24 hours.

Comment: select Data, count(Data) as count, ... group by (Data)

Comment: Is this a MongoDB question?  I see you tagged MongoDB, but this appears to be a columnar database and you are using a sql statement....

Comment: @barrypicker
I can accept the answer in mongodb statement

Comment: MongoDB has a $bucket aggregation stage.  I can't test your data since its not valid JSON..   See https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/bucket/